# Увеличить точность распознавания нейросети

Tags: python

Задача заключается в необходимости добиться точности распознавания тестовых данных (5 классов из библиотеки CIFAR100) не ниже 0.9 (мне ради интереса хотя бы 80-85% добиться). У меня в среднем держится на 70% (лучший результат был стабильно 75 на последних эпохах)
Менял количество слоев, эпох, функции обучения, оптимайзер (Adam), вроде как все перепробовал, но ничего не изменилось практически (местами было хуже), а так же закончился лимит использования GPU на проекте от гугла, поэтому взываю к помощи :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.datasets import cifar100
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
num_classes = 100
(x_train_img, y_train_img), (x_test_img, y_test_img) = cifar100.load_data()
#Форма массива обучающих образов:
print('x_train shape:', x_train_img.shape)
#Форма массива меток обучающих образов:
print('y_train shape:', y_train_img.shape)
#Количество обучающих образов:
print(x_train_img.shape[0], 'train samples')
#Количество тестовых образов:
print(x_test_img.shape[0], 'test samples')
#Форма массива тестовых образов:
print('x_test shape:', x_test_img.shape)
#Форма массива меток тестовых образов:
print('y_test shape:', y_test_img.shape)

x_train=x_train_img[tuple(np.where((y_train_img[:,0] == 6)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 7)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 14)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 18)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 24)))]
y_train_5=y_train_img[tuple(np.where((y_train_img[:,0] == 6)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 7)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 14)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 18)|(y_train_img[:,0] == 24)))]
x_test=x_test_img[tuple(np.where((y_test_img[:,0] == 6)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 7)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 14)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 18)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 24)))]
y_test_5=y_test_img[tuple(np.where((y_test_img[:,0] == 6)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 7)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 14)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 18)|(y_test_img[:,0] == 24)))]
#Форма массива обучающих образов:
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
#Форма массива меток обучающих образов:
print('y_train shape:', y_train_5.shape)
#Форма массива тестовых образов:
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)
#Форма массива меток тестовых образов:
print('y_test shape:', y_test_5.shape)

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train_5, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test_5, num_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255.
x_test /= 255. 

model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.15),
    Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.25), 
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(num_classes,  activation='softmax')
])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
his = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=32, epochs=50)

print('точность на обучающих данных', model.evaluate(x_train, y_train))
print('точность на тестовых данных', model.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Точность: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: Ну я посмотрел, там хитрые какие-то картинки в трейне. У вас переусложнённая сеть, на гораздо более простой учится нормально, при этом обучение на трейне под 100% получается, а на тесте стабильно провал до 60%-70%. Ну вот такой датасет. Там как-то хитро нужно генерализировать модель, т.е. не усложнять, а, возможно, упрощать. Хитрить как-то, чтобы под тест именно приспособить как-то умудриться. То, что вы хотите могут только какие-то SOTA решения, нужно гуглить бумаги по этому датасету какие выходили, какие сетки могут его с таким качеством понимать. Вручную это вы вряд ли сами добьётесь.

Comment: SOTA варианты можно посмотреть тут: https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-cifar-100